# Плагин jQuery.FancyBox блокирует сайт в FireFox3

Tags: jquery, firefox

В других сайтах работает, протестировала в `FireFox3` и обнаружила, что сайт блокируется. При открытии сайта открывается плагин `jQuery.FancyBox` и все, невозможно работать в `FireFox3`. Никак не могу понять, в чем проблема. Please Help.

Comment: Если сайт в сети - поделитесь ссылкой...

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать `GreyBox`.

Comment: А решения нет в `jQuery.FancyBox`?